# realtime replication of Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-replication

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2  database instance and some data collection scripts which collect data from various FTP, SFTP sources. Now I want to have another installation of this system, but I cannot get these FTP feeds in the new remote location. I am looking for a simplest way to have a real-time copy of this database on the new remote machine. I am aware i can come up with some scripts to do this , but I am particularly looking for a solution which will let me use some feature of SQL Server 2008 to this.

Simply put, what I need is a new database at location B which is always in sync (realtime) with database at location A. Does any feature of SQL Server lets me achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should read up on mirroring, replication, and log shipping. They are different technologies that achieve what you're after but they have some different aspects that you'll want to compare.

Comment: I am currently looking into the avialable options for replication. We need real time replication - not bulk, but by each simple update on transaction db to reporting db. Which we hope reduces the *burden* on transactional db grately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three features in sql server.
1.Replication
2.logshipping
3.Mirroring

1. [Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151314%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):It replicates every transaction from server A to Server B .Its up to date data willbe available in B also.To read about replication.
2. [Logshipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx): this is nothing but automating backup and restore but your B Server will be in standby mode you cant read the data.
3. Refers here for [Mirroring.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx#Benefits)